# Social Media Site | Laravel | Feed System And Share System | Design for fetch feeds

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, social-networking, lumen

I'm Creating a Social Media Site From Scratch in Laravel (API).

**Tables :**

```
  Users 
  Posts 
  Friends
  Followers
```

**Privacy Settings :**

user have general settings for his posts public,

private and friends and post have also privacy settings public, private and friends.

**My Problem:**

1. How I can get Feeds for logged in user with these checks
2. How to Share Post Scenario works (i create a duplicate post with user_id who shares post)
3. Fetching Post with likes and comments
4. is this possible without and 3rd party packages.

Comment: for every post maintain one column where the post is public,private and friends and while display data check if the post is private don't show to others user.

Comment: You can make the share like Facebook, if you share something from a different person, it uses his post, it doesn't create a new one for you. You can do all of these above without any 3rd party packages, but I suggest you use one, it's more simple and easy. If there is a package that has all the things you listed above, I see no reason not to use one.

Comment: @pal if some user set only his friends can see his posts . 
and some of his post is private .

On fetching first check this friend settings and than check post privacy .

Comment: if im not duplicating the post for share .
and added  shared post tables and -> user_id and  post_id 
how i can manage this post come first and this same record not appears twice 
(when i scroll down )